# Setting initial value when adding a column with option GENERATED ALWAYS / BY DEFAULT in a DB2 database

Tags: sql, db2, default

Adding a column to one of my tables like this :

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE   
ADD S_CHANGED TIMESTAMP NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS FOR EACH ROW ON UPDATE AS ROW CHANGE TIMESTAMP
```

leads to an initial `S_CHANGED` value of zero (year zero) for existing rows.
Is there a way to specify a default value (e.g. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`) within the same SQL query, or is an `UPDATE` query required for that? Adding `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` causes an error.

Comment: There is no way to do this. Why would you need to set a ROW CHANGE TIMESTAMP column values manually?

Comment: Okay, thanks. You can turn that comment into an answer if you want. I was having issues (de-)serializing the initial column values. *Cannot deserialize value of type `java.sql.Timestamp` from String "+0000-12-31T23:00:00.000+0000": not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '+0000-12-31T23:00:00.000+0000': Cannot parse date "+0000-12-31T23:00:00.000+0000": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))*

Comment: You should get TIMESTAMP ('0001-01-01-00.00.00') values and process them as java.sql.Timestamp data type, not as String. Check the [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=b77ea64322e7fcbcae65e7ea5b006e7a).

Comment: I do process them as timestamps, but for some part of my API I'm migrating from one DB to an other, and therefore need to serialize/deserialize some of the data. The resulting JSON strings aren't processed correctly it seems, and I couldn't immediately figure out why. The issue could be fixed by setting a more appropriate initial timestamp, and I was curious if it could be done without an UPDATE statement.